# ERROR on Displaying Output in JOptionPane

Tags: java, user-interface

I am new to Java and i get an error if i try to display my output in JOptionPane, Please Help.
I get an error that says

javax.swing.JTextField[,217,117,150x20,layout = javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX= 0.0,alignment Y = 0.0,border =javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@fb7f7e,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=    something something.

i just referenced the code from somewhere because we had the same format, and i can't display the output.

---

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Text1 {
static Container contain;
static JFrame f;
static JPanel p;
static JLabel l,lblName,lblEmail,lblMovie,lblRole,lblSalary,lblGross;
static JTextField fName,fEmail,fMovie,fRole,fSalary,fGross;
static JButton submit;

Handler h = new Handler();

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Text1();                
}

public Text1(){
f = new JFrame("Movies");
f.setLayout(null);
contain = f.getContentPane();

p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(null);
p.setBounds(0,0,700,700);
contain.add(p);

l = new JLabel("<html>Write a program to accept the name, email address, latest movie, role, salary, box office gross. Display all the inputs and the bonus and total income.The total income came from the salary and the bonus which is the 10% of the box office gross.</html>");
l.setBounds(10,5,670,100);
p.add(l);
//--Name
lblName = new JLabel("Name: ");
lblName.setBounds(78,52,89,150);
p.add(lblName);
//--Email
lblEmail = new JLabel("Email: ");
lblEmail.setBounds(78,84,89,150);
p.add(lblEmail);
//--Movie
lblMovie = new JLabel("Latest Movie: ");
lblMovie.setBounds(78,116,130,150);
p.add(lblMovie);
//--Role
lblRole = new JLabel("Role: ");
lblRole.setBounds(78,148,89,150);
p.add(lblRole);
//--Salary
lblSalary = new JLabel("Salary: ");
lblSalary.setBounds(78,180,89,150);
p.add(lblSalary);
//--Gross
lblGross = new JLabel("Gross: ");
lblGross.setBounds(78,212,89,150);
p.add(lblGross);

//TextFields :3
fName = new JTextField();
fName.setBounds(217,117,150,20);
p.add(fName);
fEmail = new JTextField();
fEmail.setBounds(217,147,150,20);
p.add(fEmail);
fMovie = new JTextField();
fMovie.setBounds(217,180,150,20);
p.add(fMovie);
fRole = new JTextField();
fRole.setBounds(217,213,150,20);
p.add(fRole);
fSalary = new JTextField();
fSalary.setBounds(217,244,150,20);
p.add(fSalary);
fGross = new JTextField();
fGross.setBounds(217,275,150,20);
p.add(fGross);

//Buttonerino
submit = new JButton("Submit");
submit.setBounds(78,310,80,20);
submit.addActionListener(h);
p.add(submit);


f.setSize(710,710);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setResizable(false);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private class Handler implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

String name = fName.getText();
String email = fEmail.getText();
String movie = fMovie.getText();
String role = fRole.getText();
String salary = fSalary.getText();
String gross = fGross.getText();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name: " + fName +"\n Email: " +fEmail);
}   
}

}
```

Comment: Can you cut your code sample down to a [mcve], and post the whole error message?

Comment: everything got fixed now, i accidentally called the different variable that's why it was't displaying the error rather  than the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `fName` to `name` and `fEmail` to `email`

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: " + name + "\n Email: " + email);`

Comment: i tried using that answer and still gives me the same error

Comment: its not an error. you printing ```fName``` instead of ```fName.getText()```

Comment: omg thanks it actually worked, i didnt realized you didnt add the f

Answer (score 0):

you should use name instead of fName and email instead of fEmail.

```
private class Handler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    String name = fName.getText();
    String email = fEmail.getText();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name: " + name +"\n Email: " +email);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name: " + fName.getText() +"\n Email: " +fEmail.getText());`